How to create a custom component with two way v-model binding
Imagine the scenario where you have a custom component called coolComponent that consists of three input boxes:
<v-text-field v-model="from"/>
<v-text-field v-model="to"/>
<v-text-field v-model="subject"/>

These three fields actually adhere to a interface coolInterface as follows:
interface CoolInterface {
  from: string;
  to: string;
  subject: string;
}

Surprisingly after years of using vue I have never had to create a custom component that has its own v-model. So I am not sure how to actually do this but I need to create a v-model for my coolComponent such that if its initially set in the parent component the text fields would fill in with the CoolInterface object or if the user makes edits in the text boxes the v-model will update as usual. Hopefully that all makes sense!

The Vue documentation has pretty much all information you need regarding custom component v-model.  Child component just needs line of code like const model = defineModel(), now your v-model object from the parent, which implements CoolInterface, is available in the child which you've now named "model", so it would have model.from, model.to, etc...
Parent.vue
interface CoolInterface {
  from: string;
  to: string;
  subject: string;
}

const cool = ref<CoolInterface>({
  from: 'foo',
  to: 'bar',
  subject: 'baz'
})

<CoolComponent v-model="cool" />

CoolComponent.vue
const model = defineModel()

<input v-model="model.from"/>
<input v-model="model.to"/>
<input v-model="model.subject"/>


Do you not need to define the model type as CoolInterface in the defineModel?

Oddly enough to do it the only way I could make it work with setting type of model was using type: Object as PropType. Not sure why you cant set the type direclty.
